# How can I apply the JavaScript method on my Facebook page?

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, graph

I found this code, and I need to display it on my page:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://www.joshuaproject.net/upgotd.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- alternative for no javascript --><noscript>
<a href="http://www.joshuaproject.net/upgotdfeed.php">View Unreached People of the Day</a></noscript>
```

What are the steps to follow? Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2):

That is, [AFAIK](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAIK), not possible due to security reasons. The keyword is [cross-site scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use the iFrame example from the link your provided.  You can now add iFrames to your Facebook Page ( not individual user profiles ) using this process:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/